# How to add product tab for specific product type in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, tabs

How to add product tab using xml in admin? I want to show that tab particular product type.

How can i add this product tab using my custom module in magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this in `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="[Namespace]\[module]\Block\Name\Here" name="block.name.here" />
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">block_name_here</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">block.name.here</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

then create the block `[Namespace]\[module]\Block\Name\Here` that implements `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface`.

**Note:This Solution is working Only Magento 2.0x not in 2.1x**

Comment: In magento2.1 i added my custom fields in product edit using below given answer by me but i am not getting that fields value in post after click on save button. Any idea how to get this?

Comment: you just added a line in my answer saying this does not work   for 2.1. And I validated your addition. In 2.1, the product add/edit form has been changed from tabs to ui components. This does not work anymore.

Comment: So is it not possible to add custom fields using phtml?

Comment: I don't know. Most probably not. You can check how the tabs are added in the ui component for products and try to replicate the behavior.

Comment: Just got it.In input field add this `data-form-part="product_form"` and i get value of my custom fields

Answer (score 3):

Add xml file to **Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Companyname\Modulename\Block\yourblockname" name="mycustom.tab" as="mycustom" template="Companyname_Modulename::mytab.phtml" group="detailed_info">               
                <arguments>                       
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">My Custom Tab Name</argument>
                  </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add you template file to **Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/mytab.phtml**

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is for Magento 2.1.0

In catalog_product_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="product_form">
        <block name="class_session" class="[Namespace]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Tabname">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Write Name</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">33</item>
                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```